# Use C variable in Mysql

Tags: mysql, c, variables

I'm trying to pass a variable into Mysql in C.
Could someone tell me what's going wrong here:

```
char request[100];  
int id = 1;

snprintf(request, 100, "UPDATE database SET x = 1 WHERE id = %d", id);
mysql_query(&mysql, request);
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

I assume there is a problem with snprintf because this also doesn't
work:

```
snprintf(request, 100, "UPDATE database SET x = 1 WHERE id = %d", id);
mysql_query(&mysql, "UPDATE database SET x = 1 WHERE id = 1");
```

But without this `snprintf` line, code works

Comment: mysql has no idea that the `1` came as a result of a sprintf, or was in the original string. it just sees a string. if the query's not working, did you check `mysql_errno()` and `mysql_error()` to see WHY it was rejected?

Comment: I'm absolutely new in C. Could you tell me how to check that?
`code`
mysql_query(&mysql, request);
printf("%s", mysql_error);
`code`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-error.html

Comment: @MarcB Couldn't find that out...
All I know: 
`mysql_query($mysql, "UPDATE database SET x = 1 WHERE id = 1")`
Works
and `printf(request);` Shows me the good string to give to Mysql...

Comment: try static char request[100];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Claris

Solution:

```
static char request[100] = {0};  
int id = 1;

snprintf(request, 100, "UPDATE database SET x = 1 WHERE id = %d", id);
mysql_query(&mysql, request);
```

Comment: BTW, it is probably a threading issue. mysql_query does not happen immediately so when it finally gets around to processing the request the stack is filled with garbage. The static reserves space on the stack and thus prevents your string from getting clobbered.